# Why can't I generate newlines in quotes in bash?

Tags: bash, newline, quote

No matter what I do, I can't get the newlines in quotes to persist in the output. What am I to do? This is bash in OS X. My code is here: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rjurney/4634cf7301bace6fd849)

```
read -d '' sbt_text=$(cat <<"EOF"
#!/bin/bash
SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M";
java $SBT_OPTS -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
EOF
)

echo $sbt_text

#!/bin/bash > SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"; > java -jar /sbt-launch.jar ""
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you probably want is this:

```
IFS= read -d '' -r sbt_text <<"EOF"
#!/bin/bash
SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M";
java $SBT_OPTS -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
EOF

echo "$sbt_text"
```

While your `read` command doesn't work as posted, ***not double-quoting* `$sbt_text` will invariably perform [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting)** (and also [pathname expansion (globbing)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs)), which, **when passed to `echo`, means that any interior whitespace is normalized to a *single space***.

**In order to preserve the value of a variable *as-is* in POSIX-like shells** - without subjecting it to the [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) described above - **you must *double-quote* it.**

With respect to the `read` command, note that:

- `-r` prevents usually unintended interpretation of `\` instances in the input.
- Prepending `IFS=` ensures that each line in the here-document is preserved as-is with respect to whitespace (no trimming of leading and trailing whitespace)
- There's no need for a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) (`$(...)`) with `cat`, because `<<` (a [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument)) directly provides stdin input, which is where `read` takes its input from.

  - By using `sbt_text=$(...)` in your `read` command, you essentially made the output of the command substitution (`$(...)`) *part of the (ultimately invalid) variable name* rather than providing *input*, causing `read` to still wait for stdin input.
  - Using *just* assignment `sbt_text=$(cat <<"EOF" ...)` (without `read`) would almost have given you what you want (although at the expense of a call to external utility `cat`), except that the command substitution would have stripped any trailing newlines.

Answer (score 2):

You should **quote your variables**:

```
echo "$sbt_text"
```

This prevents Bash from doing **word splitting** (and **globbing**, i.e. expanding wildcard characters like `*` and `?`) after substituting your variable (parameter expansion). Note that setting `IFS` for `read` does not prevent word splitting on the `echo` command line. Try this for fun:

```
( IFS= ; echo $sbt_text )
```

vs.

```
IFS= echo $sbt_text ### won't work
```

The second example will not work - the subshell (`( )`) is necessary here because `IFS` is interpreted by the calling shell for word splitting in contrast to being interpreted by `read` in the question's code example.

Of course this works too (but "ruins" your `IFS`):

```
IFS= ; echo $sbt_text
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that clearing IFS isn't sufficient for `echo $foo` to be fully equivalent with `echo "$foo"`: Compare behavior when `foo='*'`.